# Userscript to bypass "You are now leaving" page

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

A web site's links external links all redirect to a "You are now leaving" page.

When I copy the originally posted link-URL, they look like this:

```
https://www.flashback.org/leave.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.swatab.com%2F%3Flang%3Den
```

Page HTML:

```
<a href="/leave.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.swatab.com%2F%3Flang%3Den"
target="_blank">http://www.swatab.com/?lang=en</a>
```

I would like to create a userscript that bypasses the **/leave.php** page and redirects me to the true link on click.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: 1. search for all links starting with "/leave.php" 2. decode the url from the query param, eg using decodeURIComponent() 3. replace the href attribute

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any particular problem I can help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a job for a relatively standard redirect script.

Note the use of `@run-at document-start` and of `location.replace`<sup>[Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)</sup>.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Flashback.org, skip the "You are now leaving" page
// @match       *://www.flashback.org/leave.php*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var targUrlEnc = location.search.replace (/\?u=/i, "");
if (targUrlEnc) {
    var targUrl = decodeURIComponent (targUrlEnc);
    location.replace (targUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for